# Android : FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Tags: android

I am new in Android Studio. Now am creating tab with swipe. While executing am getting an error like Fatal Execption.

**Logcat**

```
 2497-2497/com.polus.binil.test E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.polus.binil.test, PID: 2497
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.polus.binil.test/com.polus.binil.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.polus.binil.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148
```

Here is the MainActivity

**MainActivity**

```
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
  import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
  import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
  import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;


   public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {


private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private android.app.ActionBar actionBar;


// Tab titles
private String[] tabs = {"Top Rated", "Games", "Movies"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Initilization
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
actionBar.setNavigationMode(android.app.ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);



    // Adding Tabs
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener((android.app.ActionBar.TabListener) this));

    }

    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {

        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

}
}
```

Can Any one please help to resolve this issue

Comment: NullPointerException in MainActivity.java line number 42

Comment: Which is line MainActivity.java:42

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
actionBar = getActionBar();
```

It'll obviously will be null, because you extend `FragmentActivity` here which doesn't support action bars. Replace it with the `ActionBarActivity` and change `getActionBar()` to `getSupportActionBar()`.

Comment: @BinilSurendran please accept one of the answers than. :)

Comment: @BinilSurendran just click the tick button next to one of the answers to show that it's accepted. most of the time people on SO answer the questions to get the points for accepted answers. so, if they see that you don't accept answers, they won't answer your questions anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible causes:

1 - the ViewPager's id in activity_main.xml is not `pager`, therefore `viewpager` is null. Check if the id is correct.

2 - getActionBar() returns null. Check if `actionBar` is null, before calling `actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);`

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `actionBar = getActionBar();` with `actionBar = getSupportActionBar();` I think here getActionBar() is null